# What's the best way to format this simple HTML form using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have have a simple HTML form with say four input widgets (see below)...two lines with two widgets on each line.  However, when this renders it is pretty ugly.  I want the whole form to be indented from the edge of the left page say 40px and I want the left edge of the widgets to line up with each other and the right edge of the labels to line up.  I also want to be able to specify a minimum distance between the right edge of the first widget and the label of the widget next to it.  How would I do this using CSS?  Basically so it looks something like:

```
            Name:  _____________     Common Names:  _____________
         Version:  ____________            Status:  ____________
```

See current un-formatted HTML below:

```
<form name="detailData">
<div id="dataEntryForm">
<label>
 Name:  <input type="text" class="input_text" name="ddName"/>  Common Names: <input type="text" class="input_text" name="ddCommonNames"><P>
 Version: <input type="text" class="input_text" name="ddVer"/>  Status:  <select name="ddStatus"><option value="A" selected="selected">Active</option><option value="P">Planned</option><option value="D">Deprecated</option>
</label>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=input+form+layout+[css]

Comment: Go on, use a table.  You know you want to.  ;-)  PS: each `input` should have its own `label`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic kickoff example:

```
<div id="dataEntryForm">
    <div class="entry">
        <label for="ddName">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="input_text" id="ddName" name="ddName">
    </div>
    <div class="entry">
        <label for="ddCommonNames">Common Names:</label>
        <input type="text" class="input_text" id="ddCommonNames" name="ddCommonNames">
    </div>
    <div class="entry">
        <label for="ddVer">Version:</label>
        <input type="text" class="input_text" id="ddVer" name="ddVer">
    </div>
    <div class="entry">
        <label for="ddStatus">Status:</label>
        <select id="ddStatus" name="ddStatus"><option value="A" selected="selected">Active</option><option value="P">Planned</option><option value="D">Deprecated</option></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

with this CSS:

```
#dataEntryForm {
    width: 600px;
}
#dataEntryForm .entry {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
}
#dataEntryForm .entry label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

[Live demo](http://jsbin.com/oqire/3).

Comment: PS: if you want IE6 support (for some reason), replace `display: inline-block;` of `label` by `display: block; float: left;`. Again, it's a kickoff example. Play with widths/margins/paddings of the labels/inputs to make it look the way you want.

Comment: Being pretty new to css...what does the "for" indicate exactly?  What is that a tag for?

Comment: Nevermind...got it.  "for" Specifies which form element a label is bound to

Comment: Yup, the bonus is, if you click it, the associated input element with same ID will gain focus. It's an accessibility feature. Screenreaders and so on. It's actually a HTML feature, not CSS.

Comment: Actually, since I wanted two fields per line, there should only be two <div class="entry"> tags around the two fields sets...one around "Name" and "Common Names" and one around "Version" and "Status" if I switch it to that then it works regardless of the width of the form.

Comment: You would however probably like to give the inputs the same fixed width then. It won't work if there's e.g. a `select` in the 1st column.

Answer (score 0):

For the text boxes you could do something like this:

```
.input_text {
      background-color:transparent;
      border-top:none;
      border-left:none;
      border-right:none;
      border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
```

The select boxes will be more difficult to style like that, and you may want to look into a Javascript workaround to style it.  Something like this would help:

http://www.mypocket-technologies.com/jquery/SelectBoxPlugin/

Answer (score 0):

http://reisio.com/temp/form1.html

Remove `clear: left;` from the `li` rule and set `width` for `ul` and `li` if you want two or more side by side.